# Coding for data compression with large target's symbol set (where the target symbol set is larger than the source symbol set)

Tags: coding-theory, discrete-optimization, compression

For data compression, every codding that I've seen is binary. It means we convert a language with $N$ symbol size to a language with $M=2$ symbol size. For example, in Huffman coding, the goal is to find a binary coding ($M=2$) for each alphabet of English language ($N=26$).
If $M$ is not equal to $2$ and have a value **larger than $N$**, is there any method to find good coding (or optimal coding) for compression? Is there any research for this type of problem?
Is it a right assumption that when the target symbol size is larger, the goal is to find a map from a subset of source symbols to one target symbol?

Comment: I don't know where are studying from, but most textbooks  (in particular Cover & Thomas, probably the most popular one) develop the theory of data compression in general, for $q-$ary source codes, though binary codes are by far the most used and studied. In particular, C&T discusses how the Huffman coding is done with a ternary code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's correct but our problem is when $M>N$ and the problem is to find a map from a sequence of source symbols to one target symbol.

Answer (score 2):

The same idea applies.  You want each character to have a choice of $\frac 1M$ to come at each position in the message.  That maximized the information provided by that character.  If $N=7,M=11$ and the characters in the alphabet come in proportions $3,2,2,1,1,1,1$ you can assign three codes to the first one, two to the next two, and one code to the others and everything works perfectly.  Of course I made up the example so it would.  You can view runs of three characters in the original text as one character in a $7^3=343$ character alphabet, then you have $N \lt M$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In your solution, the result is a sequence of target symbols with the same length as source that the probability of symbols is uniform, but what I want is coding that data in the target codding has (expected) minimum length. I think for this goal, the problem is to find a map from a sequence of source symbols to one target symbol. Is there any probabilistic view of this problem?

Comment: You can use each symbol in the target alphabet to stand for more than one symbol in the source.  The same way encoding English letters in binary might have letters with code lengths of $2-7$ bits, with the short codes representing common letters, you can assign triplets (or other number) of source letters to codes in the target alphabet.  The codes can again be variable length so that common triplets are represented by short codes.

Comment: Yes, this method can compress data but it's not optimal codding. The first shortcoming is the effect of how we split the input data.
For example, in the English language it may be good to consider words as target symbols set and split based on space instead of fixed window size.